# Graph-tool vertex label with add_edges_from

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graph-tool

I tried my best to look for the solution online, but cannot seem to find one for my `graph_tool` network. I have a pandas dataframe `df` that has three columns: `id_source`, `id_target`, `weight`. The `id_source` and `id_target` contain names in text form. I want to use them as vertex labels. However, when adding edges from a pandas dataframe, I must set `hashed=True`. The code then looks like this

```py
from graph_tool.all import *

g = Graph()
eweight = g.new_ep('double')
vmap = g.add_edge_list(df.values, eprops=[eweight], hashed=True)
```

My objective is to draw this small network with vertex labels. I am stuck and can't figure out the solution on how to add that vertex property when I do not know the order by which each new node is introduced in the graph through the `g.add_edge_list()` function.

Should I add the vertices first? And then perform the `add_edge_list` function on the graph. Will the vertex names (or labels) be recognized by the second step?

Comment: What library are you using to make the graph? I need to see the documentation for `Graph.add_edge_list` to give an informed answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth, I am using the `graph_tool` library. Will edit my question to make this clearer. It's only indicated in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the `vmap`. It's there all along. When you index the `vmap`, it will get the label names.

- `vmap[0]` would be the label for the first vertex recorded.
- `vmap[1]` for the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `Graph.add_edge_list`:

> Add a list of edges to the graph, given by edge_list, which can be an iterator of (source, target) pairs where both source and target are vertex indexes, or a numpy.ndarray of shape (E,2), where E is the number of edges, and each line specifies a (source, target) pair. If the list references vertices which do not exist in the graph, they will be created.

You have passed `df.values` for `edge_list`, which has three columns (ie a shape of (E, 3)), but two columns are expected (a shape of (E, 2)).

Try this:

```py
g.add_edge_list(df[['id_source', 'id_target']].to_numpy(), eprops=[eweight], hashed=True)
```

I suspect that `eprops` should be `df['weight']`, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, Steele. The `add_edge_list` function automatically detects the additional columns as edge property (`eprops`). Essentially, with `eprops = [eweight]`, we are telling the system to assign the edge property name `eweight` to the third column. I still need to add a vertex property label here.